# ¿Balé o Ballet - Chalé o Chalet?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

He notado que en España tienden a pronunciar las palabras francesas de forma más cercana al original, pero no es así en México donde se acostumbra pronunciar las *tes* de palabras como *chalet* o *ballet*. Tengo curiosidad de saber que tan extendida está una u otra forma en los demás países hispanohablantes y cuál es la forma más usada ya sea escrita o hablada.

Comment: Yo lo escribo como en francés y lo pronuncio como en francés.  Y lo he visto y oído así en México.

Answer (score 3):

Lista con los 25 países de habla hispana.

- Argentina
- Belize
- Bolivia
- **Chile**: Siempre se escribe la *t* final. La pronunciación depende del caso. En *chalet, ballet, cabaret y carnet* depende del grado de formalidad adoptado; normalmente hay un leve bloqueo con la lengua que nunca llega a ser un chasquido. (La palabra *carnet* es de uso diario en Chile). En el caso de *bidet* y *corset* no se pronuncia la t final. En el caso de *toilet* se pronuncia como en francés, cerca de "tualet". En palabras de otros orígenes, como *clóset, hábitat, test, tarot y debut* se pronuncia y escribe la t.
- Colombia
- Costa Rica
- Cuba
- Ecuador
- El Salvador
- **España**: Favorece el uso escrito de ["chalet"](http://www.idealista.com/news/inmobiliario/top-idealista/2013/04/29/612011-los-20-chalets-nuevos-mas-baratos-de-espana-tabla) y ["ballet"](http://balletnacional.mcu.es/index.php/en/). La pronunciación tiende a reflejar esta preferencia, pero puede haber variaciones en distintas regiones. Incluso, aunque la RAE sólo recoge *"carné"* (y es lo que se suele ver escrito con mayor frecuencia) no es difícil encontrar también [*"carnet"*](http://www2.cordoba.gov.ar/portal/index.php/secretaria-de-transporte/subsecretaria-de-transito/carnet-de-conducir/) (carnet de conducir; carnet joven) y escuchar una pronunciación acorde.
- Filipinas
- Guinea Equatorial
- Guatemala
- Honduras
- México: Se escriben como en el francés "Ballet" y "Chalet" y se pronuncian tal como está escrito.
- Nicaragua
- Panamá
- Paraguay
- Perú
- Puerto Rico
- Republica Dominicana
- Sáhara occidental
- Uruguay
- Venezuela

Comment: Dado que puede ser difícil que una sola persona pueda saber qué forma prevalece sobre la otra en cada país, he iniciado una "respuesta colaborativa" (community wiki answer). Cualquier usuario puede editar la respuesta y aportar la información que tenga, y así completar los países que vayan faltando (con los que el usuario sepa por procedencia, porque ha vivido allí, porque lo ha investigado, etc).

Comment: En España favorecen las terminaciones con *t*? Creí que preferían las formas hispanizadas.

Comment: @Jaime veo cada año más y más gente que escribe con é, sobre todo en el plural, pero imagino que la preferencia original por -et sería por los catalanes que ya tienden a pronunciar -ed como si fuese -et

Comment: @Jaime, precisamente el otro día, antes de ver tu post leía en la prensa internacional una noticia sobre prisioneros del IS y el artículo usaba la palabra "chalet" ([_El chalet de los "Beatels"_](http://www.elmundo.es/internacional/2015/03/17/55070900ca4741c5598b4585.html))

Comment: Por mi experiencia, en España algunas de estas palabras mantienen la t final siempre (como *ballet*; si leo *balé* me costará un rato saber a qué se refieren). Pero para otras diría que la forma hispanizada se va haciendo cada vez más común: *carné*, *chalé*, *vermú*...

Answer (score 1):

En España antiguamente (hasta los años 80 y 90) la forma correcta era la acabada en "t" (carnet). Pero dado que la mayoría de la gente omitía ese sonido al hablar e incluso al escribir, en 2003 o 2004 la RAE lo cambió por la forma hispanizada, haciendo que la forma correcta sea sin la "t" y con el acento correspondiente (carné) y la forma con "T" pasó a ser obsoleta pero no incorrecta. Por ello aún se ve escrito en algunos lugares, ya sea porque sean textos anteriores al cambio o porque se deba a gente que no se siente cómoda o de acuerdo con el cambio e insiste en seguir usando la forma antigua.